# UISwitch TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have several cells with a UISwitch as the accessory view and everything as far as data being correct is fine the I toggle them. The issue I'm having is that when I toggle one and then scroll, another one is toggled and when I scroll back the one I toggled is no longer on. I'm assuming this has to do with the cells being reloaded.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16:
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

            if cell == nil
            {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            }

            cell?.selectionStyle = .none
            cell?.textLabel?.text = questions[indexPath.row]
            cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

            let answerSwitch = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
            answerSwitch.isOn = false
            answerSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchToggled(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            answerSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
            cell?.accessoryView = answerSwitch

            return cell!
        case 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! RAProfileQuestionDetailCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.questionLabel.text = questions[indexPath.row]
            cell.answerField.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolbar
            cell.answerField.tag = indexPath.row

            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionCell", for: indexPath) as! RAProfileQuestionCell
            return cell
        }
    }
```

**switchToggled:**

```
@objc func switchToggled(sender: Any) {
        let answerSwitch = sender as! UISwitch
        print(answerSwitch.tag)
        switch answerSwitch.tag {
        case 0:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.pre_existing = true
            } else {
                self.pre_existing = false
            }
        case 1 :
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.take_medication = true
            } else {
                self.take_medication = false
            }
        case 3:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.suicide = true
            } else {
                self.suicide = false
            }
        case 4:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.previous_treatment = true
            } else {
                self.previous_treatment = false
            }
        case 6:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.surgery = true
            } else {
                self.surgery = false
            }
        case 8:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.family_substance_abuse = true
            } else {
                self.family_substance_abuse = false
            }
        case 10:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.allergies = true
            } else {
                self.allergies = false
            }
        case 12:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.other_drug_use = true
            } else {
                self.other_drug_use = false
            }
        case 14:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.alcohol = true
            } else {
                self.alcohol = false
            }
        case 16:
            if answerSwitch.isOn {
                self.tobacco = true
            } else {
                self.tobacco = false
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know you could just do `self.pre_existing = answerSwitch.isOn`. That'd save you 4 lines per case.

Comment: Yeah. I realized that after writing it. Not sure what I was thinking. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my initial glance, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath `answerSwitch.isOn = false` is telling the switch to be off every time a cell comes onto the screen. Since it looks like you store a bunch of booleans based on whether the switch is on or off, you should use those variables to tell the switch what state it should be.

It should look something more like `answerSwitch.isOn = self.tobacco` (or which ever property it should be at that indexPath). Doing it this way should persist the switch state.

Answer (score 1):

Table cells are reused , plus here you create another 1 with `false` as default

```
let answerSwitch = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
answerSwitch.isOn = false
answerSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchToggled(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
answerSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
cell?.accessoryView = answerSwitch
```

but instead you need

```
answerSwitch.isOn = // set old value
```

---

The same switch you do in `switchToggled` should be done in `cellForRowAt` according to the `indexPath.row` , or create a model array but your problem is having a messy cells , so array implementation would be not easy a little bit

Comment: To add to this answer. Its for this reason that a lot of developers build subclasses of UITableViewCell when dealing with cells that contain UI controls. At the very least making a model or a struct to keep in an array to apply to each cell. Not only does it make debugging easier but it keeps the code nice and clean. Just an idea.